# How can I toggle between 2 images

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use this code to toggle between a play and pause button but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I get it toggle between the 2 images when the are clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/aFzG9/1/

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function()
{
    if($(this).html() == "<img src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>")
    {
        $(this).html("<img src="http://maraa.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/pause-in-times-of-conflict.png width="60px" height="60px"/>");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).html("<img src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>");
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A different maybe easier way to handle it:

http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/1/

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});​

<div id="infoToggler">
  <img src="image1.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>
  <img src="image2.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat solution. I'm assuming .find('img') returns an array of all images?

Comment: The find will return an array and toggle their visibility

Comment: This is so cool. What if I have 10 icons inside one div and I want to toggle each icon on and off upon clicking?

Comment: @HomeMade That's a different question but there are different ways to achieve it. You could add a class or data atrribute for each pair and that's what you'd toggle is one option.

Answer (score 20):

### Pure HTML/CSS

```css
label.tog > input {
  display: none; /* Hide the checkbox */
}

label.tog > input + span {
  text-indent: -9000px; /* Make text Accessible but not visible */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: center / contain no-repeat url("//i.stack.imgur.com/gmP6V.png"); /*Play*/
}

label.tog > input:checked + span {
  background-image: url("//i.stack.imgur.com/ciXLl.png"); /*Pause*/
}
```

```html
<label class="tog">
   <input type="checkbox" checked>
   <span>Button Play Pause</span>
</label>
```

---

### Toggle inner span's images using jQuery

Useful cause there's no new request to the server to load images:

```
<span class="tog">
   <img src="play.png">
   <img src="pause.png" style="display:none;">
</span>
```

```
$(".tog").click(function(){
  $('img',this).toggle();
});
```

---

Or, let's say we have this HTML and the `.tog` image selector:

```
<img class="tog" src="play.png"/>
```

### Using Array.prototype.reverse()

```
var togSrc = [ "play.png", "pause.png" ];

$(".tog").click(function() {
   this.src =  togSrc.reverse()[0];
});
```

---

### Using the current `src` value and `String.prototype.match()`

Useful if you don't know the initial state (play? pause?)

```
var togSrc = [ "play.png", "pause.png" ];

$(".tog").click(function() {
  this.src = togSrc[ this.src.match('play') ? 1 : 0 ];
});
```

**NOTE:** for the last two examples you need to pre-load your images, to prevent the time-gap the browsers makes to request and load a new image from the server.

Comment: This does not work anymore, since the `toggle(Function, Function)`-method was deprecated and removed in [jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: @LukasKnuth thanks! Very true, old answer, **I modernized it.**

Comment: this only works if the first option in the togSrc array is always selected after the page is loaded, if you use this for favourit and the img is the 2nd in the array you have to click 2 times the first time you click the div.

Comment: @SvenB **Edited**. Now you can choose the one that best suits your needs

Comment: What do you mean with: NOTE: for the last two examples you need to pre-load your images,   nice edit !

Comment: @SvenB so, the images URLs are inside our array `togSrc`, right? Which means the browser loaded only one image (i.e: the play image) cause in the SRC of the `<img src="">`. After you click the image we're setting a new `src` path to our image (the pause image) which means that our poor browser needs to send an image request to the server to load a new image. What the user sees is a *Delay* in the appearance of the *Pause* button. Subsequent clicks will not have that delay cause the images are cached. I'll leave it to you on How to do an image preload with the bunch of questions here on SO! :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i just add the image under it with display:none they are pre loaded that way ;) (i used Using Array.prototype.reverse()) thanks for the help and good explenation

Comment: @SvenB another (probably better) way (I have not the time to add it right now) is to set in CSS two classes, ".pause" and ".play" (now the browser will preload the images backgrounds!) and just shap that element's background images by using jQuery's `toggleClass()` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="infoToggler"><img src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png" width="60px" height="60px"/></div>
$(document).ready(function(){
var src1 = "http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png";
var src2 = "http://maraa.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/pause-in-times-of-conflict.png";
$("#infoToggler").click(function(){
   var src = $('#infoToggler img').attr('src'); 
   if(src == src1){$('#infoToggler img').attr('src',src2);}
   else{$('#infoToggler img').attr('src',src1);}
});
```

})​

it's working, i had checked..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.toggle()` function. I've updated your fiddle. Also, you hadn't escaped the quotes properly in your image tags.

```
$("#infoToggler").toggle(function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="http://maraa.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/pause-in-times-of-conflict.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>');
});​
```