# I want to run PHP code and change image when clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got some HTML with this image and this data-id.

```
<img id="test" src="image1.png" data-id="12345" />
```

I would like to change `image1.png` for `image2.png`, or change `image2.png` for `image1.png` when the image is clicked.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#test").click(function () { var $id = $(this).attr('data-id') });    

$.ajax({
    url:"test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id = $id },
    success:function(){ }

 });

});

</script>
```

And here is my test.php script.

```
<?php echo  $dataid; ?>
```

I meet some difficulties with Ajax and JQuery because I'm not used to it...

Comment: You mean changing the source of an image dynamically and will get it from request using ajax?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen : yes

Comment: @Fred-ii- : my PHP script is very simplified in the example... How could I execute a PHP script or would the data-id information be transmitted with a toggle ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714500/jquery-toggle-images one of many after Googling "toggle an image with jquery and php". This took me "3 seconds".

Comment: here's another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462544/how-can-i-toggle-between-2-images

Comment: @Fred-ii- : and concerning the PHP script ?

Comment: @Guillaume maybe search your problem first, try to work around before posting it. In your case, that will never be a good practice, don't ever practice that toggle via ajax

Comment: @Fred-ii- Both your answers don't take into account the fact that I need ajax : my PHP script is far more complicated, and I don't just need to toggle an image.

Comment: I'm trying to get something similar to the like icone from Instagram. That's why I don't just need to toggle an image... I also need to update my database without refresh.

Comment: Honestly; you couldn't add "and ajax" to that? I'm not going to include the (many) links (I found) this time, *you* need to do this and *you* really need to try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the image in a div. whenever click on image retrieve the id and pass to test.php via ajax and echo the response inside the div

**mainpage**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#toggle").on('click', '#test', function()
{
    var $id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: { id: $id },
        success: function(theResponse) {
            $('#toggle').html(theResponse);
            }
    });
});


});
</script>

<div id="toggle">
<img id="test" src="image1.png" data-id="12345" />
</div>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
# Get Id here
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

# for testing; remove this
echo $id;

# change here date-id and src; if it is dynamic do the database select and display image
echo '<img id="test" src="image2.png" data-id="54321" />';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot. How is it possible to get back to `image1.png` when clicked once more ?

Comment: each click pass the data-id; check it in test.php. If the data-id is __ display image1.png